# update a model and create a pdf in the same moment in django

Tags: python, django

I try to update a model (factures) I used:
in models.py

```
class TypeFact(models.Model):
type = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Type")

def __str__(self):
    return self.type
class Factures(models.Model):
num_fact = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, verbose_name="Numero")
type_fact = models.ForeignKey('TypeFact', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Type_Facture')
importance = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Importance",null=True, default=None, blank=True)
closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.num_fact + "/" + str(self.type_fact)
```

in forms.py I just create a field based of a model Typefact

```
class FormFactClose(forms.Form):
chosen = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label="Choix",
    queryset=models.TypeFact.objects.all(),
    required=False,
)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(FormFactClose, self).clean()
    khiar = cleaned_data.get("chosen")
    result=models.TypeFact.objects.filter(type=khiar)
```

I try to update a model factures by views.py

```
def close(request):
if len(request.POST) > 0:
    form = FormFactClose(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        choix = form.cleaned_data['type']
        filt = Factures.objects.filter(type_fact__id= choix)
        filt.update(closed=1)
        return render(request, 'close.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'welcome2.html', {'form': form})
        # Le formulaire n'a pas été envoyé
else:
    form = FormFactClose()
    return render(request, 'close.html', {'form': form})
```

I haven't an error but it not work
In the samme moment I want to create a pdf for the list update, but i don't know how to do it
I search a help

Answer (score 0):

You must use Reportlab module for Python